# Send mail from Wordpress Website with POST request

Tags: java, wordpress, okhttp

I want to send a pin recovery email for users. I can't find tutorials on how to do this so. Here's what i've got so far in Java. Just sends a POST request with the information

```
    private void sendTestEmail() {
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("to", to)
            .addFormDataPart("subject", subject)
            .addFormDataPart("message", message)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
}
```

Url is just the root of my website

Not sure where to go from here. I setup a SMTP server on the website. I want to call wp_mail() from my website, but I don't know how to. Thanks

Comment: What do you want ? Send email via java.mail or send post request to your wordpress site ?

Comment: @lord_hokage I want to tell my website to send an email to the address I give it

Comment: @lord_hokage I want to tell my website to send an email to the address I give it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. First you can use javax mail and second spring boot starter mail.

For javax, you can check [javax mail](http://www.baeldung.com/java-email) tutorial and this [spring mail](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-email) tutorial helps you if you pick spring.